# How to select areas from openstreetmap in django?

Tags: python, django, openstreetmap, shapefile, ogr

I would like to build a django webapp. One part of this should allow the user to interactively select geographic areas from a map. The map should come from openstreetmap, and the user should be able to do different kinds of selections:

- freehand
- rectangles
- circles

For further processing, the selected area needs to be converted into a shapefile / OGR geometry.

Probably there are already solutions for the individual steps, and I'll have to integrate those. So my question is:

- What's the best way to display a OSM map in my django app?
- How do I select the regions?
- How can I convert the selection to an OGR geometry?

*Note:* If I should make this into seperate questions, let me know!

Comment: What have you found online so far?

Comment: Well, there's geodjango, which has GEOS bindings, which I could probably convert to OGR. Regarding the OSM integration, I haven't really found anything which looked useful to me. Some projects which have map stuff in the django admin, but I want the map and selection be exposed to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should rather asked this question on the [SE GIS site](http://gis.stackexchange.com) because it is rather about web mapping techniques than django.

Concerning your questions I advice you to have a look at leaflet, a js library that makes map and geometry integration very easy. I both use them in my django projects. For geometry creation you need a add-on called [leaflet draw](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw). I haven't used it yet but it looks very promising.

To create shapefiles I often use leaflet it in combination with a pure python package called [pyshp](http://code.google.com/p/pyshp/).

I hope this helps to get you started.